# Age of consent per country database

Tags: data-request, data.gov, legal

I am looking for a DB of the [age of consent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_consent) per state/country. I found [this](http://www.webistry.net/jan/consent.html) list for the states in the USA.

1. Is there an official database I can use for the USA?
2. Are there any databases for other countries?

Comment: The table's not that easy, as there are other factors at play.  Age of Consent can be the [minimum age to get married](http://family.findlaw.com/marriage/state-by-state-marriage-age-of-consent-laws.html) or the the upper bounds of [Stauatory Rape](http://www.cga.ct.gov/2003/olrdata/jud/rpt/2003-r-0376.htm).  The statuatory rape can be affected by the age of the second party -- so if there's less than 2 years of difference in age, it may be legal when it wouldn't be if there were 6 years differencein age.  Minimum marriage age might have exceptions for with parent's permission.  (eg, 13 in KY)

Comment: ... although 16 w/out parents ... statuatory rape is anyone under 12 ... or under 14 if you're over 16 ... or under 16 if you're over 21 ... so you could say KY's age of consent is one of `{ 12, 13, 14, 16 }` ... Maryland is more confusing, as there may not be a n age at which all sexual content is illegal ... if there's a 4 year difference, and one is under 14, it's illegal, if one is over 21 and one under 15, it's illegal.  But as well as I understand the law, it's legal between a 12 & 13 year old in MD.

Answer (score 3):

The UN publishes such as list for age of consent for marriage:

http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=GenderStat&f=inID:19

Note, the age of consent for sex is in many countries lower than consent for marriage. The UN publishes this as well, but I was not able to find it at the moment.

Comment: It helps but I am looking for the minimum age for consent for sex.

Comment: Wikipedia has tables for this. I just can't find from their references a single authoritative source. Google: wikipedia legal age of consent

Comment: Thanks but I need an official source since I am using it for a law related work.